# Two radio button form

Tags: html

In my site I have 2 parts with radio button. As you can see below, is almost simmilar. But problem is that first work correctly, and second doesn't work.
What is reason of that behaviour?

Part1

```
<form class="slider__list" action="#" method="get">
      <input class="slider__radiobutton" type="radio" name="slider__radiobutton" id="slider__radiobutton_1" value="1">
      <label for="slider__radiobutton_1"></label>
      <input class="slider__radiobutton" type="radio" name="slider__radiobutton" id="slider__radiobutton_2" value="2" checked="">
      <label for="slider__radiobutton_2"></label>
      <input class="slider__radiobutton" type="radio" name="slider__radiobutton" id="slider__radiobutton_3" value="3">
      <label for="slider__radiobutton_3"></label>
      <input class="slider__radiobutton" type="radio" name="slider__radiobutton" id="slider__radiobutton_4" value="4">
      <label for="slider__radiobutton_4"></label>
    </form>
```

Second

```
<form class="testimonials__list" action="#" method="get">
      <input class="testimonials__radiobutton" type="radio" name="testimonials__radiobutton" id="testimonials__radiobutton_1" value="1">
      <label for="testimonials__radiobutton_1"></label>
      <input class="testimonials__radiobutton" type="radio" name="testimonials__radiobutton" id="testimonials__radiobutton_2" value="2" checked="">
      <label for="testimonials__radiobutton_2"></label>
      <input class="testimonials__radiobutton" type="radio" name="testimonials__radiobutton" id="testimonials__radiobutton_3" value="3">
      <label for="testimonials__radiobutton_3"></label>
      <input class="testimonials__radiobutton" type="radio" name="testimonials__radiobutton" id="testimonials__radiobutton_4" value="4">
      <label for="testimonials__radiobutton_4"></label>
    </form>
```

UPDATE:
Share full code. Not add all picture so it not very viewable but 1 radio buttons are below slider and it works, another are below testimonial and it don't work
http://codepen.io/shengofer/pen/WwRPOV

Comment: explain "the second doesn't work"

Comment: I can't switch radio button

Comment: Dont see a problem with your code. check this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONWdMB

Comment: Is there any javascript in the page or another forms? It works... could you paste the whole html page?

Comment: share code in update